# Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new' useDisclosure. A chakra ui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, chakra-ui

I'm getting the following error when I run my code but I checked and everything seems fine on my side.

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
    React 14
    onOpen use-disclosure.ts:39
    React 23
    <anonymous> main.jsx:8
```

here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalFooter,
  ModalBody,
  ModalCloseButton,
  Input,
  Textarea,
  VStack,
  Box,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useDisclosure } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { Picker } from 'emoji-mart';
import data from '@emoji-mart/data';


export const PostModal = () => {
  const [postContent, setPostContent] = useState('');
  const [selectedEmoji, setSelectedEmoji] = useState(null);
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const handlePostContentChange = (e) => {
    setPostContent(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEmojiSelect = (emoji) => {
    setSelectedEmoji(emoji.native);
  };

  const handlePostSubmit = () => {
    // Combine post content with selected emoji
    const combinedContent = selectedEmoji
      ? `${selectedEmoji} ${postContent}`
      : postContent;

    // You can handle the submission logic here
    console.log('Combined content:', combinedContent);

    // Close the modal after submission
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button ml='auto' colorScheme='red' onClick={onOpen}>Create Post</Button>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Create a Post</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            <VStack spacing={4}>
              <Textarea
                placeholder="What's on your mind?"
                value={postContent}
                onChange={handlePostContentChange}
              />

              {/* Emoji picker */}
              <Box>
                <Picker
                  data={data}
                  set="native" // You can customize the emoji set as needed
                  onSelect={handleEmojiSelect}
                />
              </Box>

              {/* Add options for uploading files or links */}
              <Box>
                {/* File upload input */}
                <Input type="file" accept="image/*, video/*" />

                {/* Link input */}
                <Input type="text" placeholder="Enter a link" />
              </Box>
            </VStack>
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={handlePostSubmit}>
              Post
            </Button>
            <Button variant="ghost" onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

The error appears to be with the useDisclosure component but I can't see what I'm doing wrong

I checked stackoverflow, I tried chatgpt, I checked chakra ui's docs to ensure that I'm using it the right way. all dependencies and liraries are installed and up to date

Comment: Which version of `@chakra-ui/react` have you installed?

Comment: I installed version 2.8.2. I believe it's the latest

Comment: I checked the source code and the only thing I can think of is a react version mismatch

Comment: I was able to pass it but had to restart building that component but until now I don't know what went wrong cause my react version is also the latest